# Hide an emission object but keep it's glare effect

Tags: compositing-nodes, visibility, glare

I'm using the glare node in the compositor to create a lens flare effect. Is there any way to make the emission object not appear in the render, but keep it's glare effect?

I've tried turning off camera ray visibility for the emission object, but then I loose the glare effect too.

Comment: I think you'll have to render it as a second layer (or indeed just a second image) and composite it over.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll give that a go.

Comment: glare set to 1 or -1, I forget which, outputs only the glare result, and you can mixrgb -> add to add it in